# Why am I able to use C# lists without writing "using System.Collections.Generic;" at the beginning of my file?

Tags: c#, list

Take a look at this simple C# program:

```
using System;

namespace testProgram
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("List element.");
            Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
List element.
```

You can see that it uses a list. I always saw on the Internet that in order to use a list, I need to add "using System.Collections.Generic;" at the beginning of my file. However, the program can run without this line, why?

Comment: This does not compile on my online compiler `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: Which compiler / IDE do you use?

Comment: @Pac0 I use visual studio community 2022.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at your project file. I *strongly* suspect it will include this:

```xml
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
```

The `ImplicitUsings` feature is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#implicitusings):

> The `ImplicitUsings` property can be used to enable and disable implicit `global using` directives in C# projects that target .NET 6 or a later version and C# 10 or a later version. When the feature is enabled, the .NET SDK adds `global using` directives for a set of default namespaces based on the type of project SDK. Set this property to `true` or `enable` to enable implicit `global using` directives. To disable implicit `global using` directives, remove the property or set it to `false` or `disable`.

Note that that means you don't need `using System;` either.

Combined with top-level statements, your whole file could actually be:

```cs
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("List element.");
Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
```

Or if the namespace is important to you:

```cs
namespace testProgram;

List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("List element.");
Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
```

Comment: Yes, this line is in my project file.